# Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components in next.js

Tags: next.js

I am using next.js on "next": "13.4.19".
the project structure is
--app
-- layout.tsx
-- page.tsx
-- [id]
--page.tsx

in the [id] page.tsx,

"use client"

```
import { Editor } from '@/components/editor';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'

export default async function PipelineDesignerEditorPage(
  { params }: { params: { pipelineId: string } }
) {
  console.log('params.pipelineId',params.pipelineId);

  const [loding, setLoding] = useState(false);
  const [pipelineData, setPipelineData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoding(true);
    let data = getPipeline(params.pipelineId);
    setPipelineData(data);
    setLoding(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: `calc(100vh - 65px)` }}>
      <Editor pipeline={pipeline} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

an error **'Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.'** appears.

I found this page is being rendered in the server side, so I modified a bit

```
'user client'
import { Editor } from '@/components/editor';
import { getPipeline } from '@/lib/pipelines/storage';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'

export default async function PipelineDesignerEditorPage(
  { params }: { params: { pipelineId: string } }
) {
  console.log('params.pipelineId',params.pipelineId);
  const pipeline = await getPipeline(params.pipelineId);
  
  const [loding, setLoding] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect');
    setLoding(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: `calc(100vh - 65px)` }}>
      <Editor pipeline={pipeline} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

it still doesn't work unless useEffect and useState is removed away.

Does it mean I can't use useState and useEffect in app->[id]->page.tsx, what about click, loading actions which needs to use useState and useEffect

Comment: Just remove the async keywords.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mixing client and server components. As the error says, async/await is only supported in server component (without `"use client"`). But, as you mentioned, `useState` and `useEffect` (or events like click) etc... are only supported in client components.

The solution is to split the 2 in 2 different components. Typically the `page.tsx` would be a server component where you fetch data and pass those to a child client component as parameter(s) where you can have state and events if needed.

On a specific note, you probably should have state and effect in the `Editor` or look at `Suspense`. See example under https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming#example

Comment: But then how do you handle errors, loading states, etc? This is all coupled to the fetching logic... you need to set states while you are fetching/after you fetch. How are you supposed to do this without being able to use `useState`?  You're supposed to change the whole way things are done and there is not even a simple example anywhere telling me how to do it? Ridiculous..

Comment: Fetching is definitively NOT coupled to local state. You can fetch without setting state and can set state without fetching... If you need to put the fetched data in a local state, you fetch them in a server component and pass them in a client component where as props where it can be put in local state there. Then you can play with the state as you like there (without refetching when you update the state).

Answer (score 19):

I used to get the same error when I tried applying `'use client'` for the whole page.

My solution is removing the `async` keyword. In this case, use:

```js
export default function PipelineDesignerEditorPage
```

instead of:

```js
export default async function PipelineDesignerEditorPage
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetching data in my page.tsx was quite frustrating as it would required me to do prop drilling. Fortunately, I discovered a more effective solution. By utilizing the `dynamic` function from the `next/dynamic` package, I was able to address the issue. Here's an example:

```js
const ChatWelcomeContent = dynamic(() => import("./chat-welcome-content"), {
  ssr: true,
});
```

This resolves the error:

> "Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only
> Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding
> 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server."

Hope it helps!